# gammu smsd server unresponsive

Tags: gammu

I have an enfora modem connected to a serial port on my server machine (which I access via ssh since it is remote) running ubuntu. Basically, it is a gsm modem that can communicate through a gsm network to talk to gps devices which also have gsm modem. I am using gammu-smsd to scan the GSM modem for received messages, then store them in postgresql database, and send the messages to the cell phones of users.

It has been working but suddenly stopped working. My /etc/gammu-smsdrc is configured. None of that configuration changed. I still have the port set to /dev/ttyS0. I checked the postgresql database and it is running. And that is the database that gammu-smsd is configured to use.

Now gammu-smsd logs to my syslog file and this is the latest output from it:

```
Jun 24 14:20:01 porkypig CRON[32512]: (www-data) CMD ([ -x /usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -a -f /etc/awstats/awstats.conf -a -r /var/log/apache2/access.log ] && /usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=awstats -update >/dev/null)
Jun 24 14:20:18 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 24 14:20:28 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 24 14:20:28 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 24 14:20:28 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too much connection errors
Jun 24 14:20:58 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 24 14:21:08 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 24 14:21:08 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 24 14:21:08 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too much connection errors
Jun 24 14:21:38 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 24 14:21:38 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Can't open device (Error opening device. Unknown, busy or no permissions.:2)
Jun 24 14:21:38 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Using PGSQL service
Jun 24 14:21:38 porkypig gammu-smsd[32416]: Disconnecting from PostgreSQL
```

Then doesn't look to comforting.

When I run

```
sudo minicom
```

It says initializing modem and displays this:

```
Welcome to minicom 2.4

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Jan 25 2010, 07:02:36.
Port /dev/ttyS0

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

But then all it gives me is a blinking cursor and typing doesn't do anything.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with minicom. AFAICT there is no way to tell minicom that you don't want to connect to a modem. It just sends a bunch of modem commands to your linux box serial console and sometime locks it up.

Comment: Any kind of short-term solution with this?